# How can I automatically redirect created ships?

Tags: endless-space

Master of Orion (I forget which one, probably II. Sing the song of reverence, amen. Ahem.) had an excellent feature in it, whereby created ships would automatically be redirected to another designated planet.

I can't find any feature in endless space (classic, no expansion) there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, but only if you install the Disharmony DLC.

**Instructions**

Hold down the left Ctrl, then click on the building system. While still holding down Ctrl, click on the destination location.

This should create a visible dotted arc that comes up out of the galactic plane from the building system and drops back down on the destination system.

To remove the rally point, hold left Ctrl, click on the building system, and then click on it again.

**Effect**

As soon as they are constructed, new ships will be made into single-ship fleets and fly toward the destination system via the shortest possible route, which may include wormholes or warp.

Comment: Thanks but I've tried this a variety of ways, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Running from Steam, but that shouldn't be an issue. Clicking on the banner, fleet or planet with Ctrl pressed and also ctrl held doesn't do anything different from normal. Alas!

Comment: @Rob I believe it's important that it's the *left* Ctrl. You might check your key bindings. When you hold Ctrl, I think there should be some small text at the top of the screen saying something like "Left Ctrl Press". I've always played from Steam, and this works just fine for me.

Comment: @Rob Oh, do you not have Disharmony installed? I think you need the DLC for this to work. The DLC is free, you should probably get it.

Comment: Aha, been avoiding it as I wanted to complete without; hmmm, okay. Thanks! Also wasn't sure that the saves would be compatible...